# Create new array from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables, sum

ok, so i have two arrays

```
Array ( 
[0] => 23225 
[1] => 23224 
[2] => 23212 
[3] => 23188 
[4] => 23048 
[5] => 23027 
[6] => 23024 
[7] => 23018 
[8] => 22994 
[9] => 22992 )

Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 2108 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22992 [day] => 21 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2168 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 2169 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 2170 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 4 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 2171 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 5 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 2172 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 6 ) 
[6] => Array ( [id] => 2173 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 10 ) 
[7] => Array ( [id] => 2174 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 11 ) 
[8] => Array ( [id] => 2175 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 12 ) 
[9] => Array ( [id] => 2176 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 13 ) 
[10] => Array ( [id] => 2177 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 16 ) 
[11] => Array ( [id] => 2178 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 17 ) 
[12] => Array ( [id] => 2179 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 18 ) 
[13] => Array ( [id] => 2180 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 19 ) 
[14] => Array ( [id] => 2181 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 20 ) 
[15] => Array ( [id] => 2182 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 23 ) 
[16] => Array ( [id] => 2183 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 24 ) 
[17] => Array ( [id] => 2184 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 25 ) 
[18] => Array ( [id] => 2185 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 26 ) 
[19] => Array ( [id] => 2186 [person] => [time_id] => 16- [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 27 ) 
[20] => Array ( [id] => 2187 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 22994 [day] => 30 ) 
[21] => Array ( [id] => 2386 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23018 [day] => 19 ) 
[22] => Array ( [id] => 2483 [person] => [time_id] => 10-- [version_id] => 23024 [day] => 2 ) 
[23] => Array ( [id] => 2484 [person] => [time_id] => 10-- [version_id] => 23024 [day] => 3 ) 
[24] => Array ( [id] => 2485 [person] => [time_id] => 10-- [version_id] => 23024 [day] => 4 ) 
[25] => Array ( [id] => 2486 [person] => [time_id] => 10-- [version_id] => 23024 [day] => 5 ) 
[26] => Array ( [id] => 2487 [person] => [time_id] => 10-- [version_id] => 23024 [day] => 6 ) 
[27] => Array ( [id] => 2592 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23027 [day] => 10 ) 
[28] => Array ( [id] => 2593 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23027 [day] => 11 ) 
[29] => Array ( [id] => 2594 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23027 [day] => 12 ) 
[30] => Array ( [id] => 2595 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23027 [day] => 13 ) 
[31] => Array ( [id] => 2877 [person] => [time_id] => 17- [version_id] => 23048 [day] => 23 ) 
[32] => Array ( [id] => 2878 [person] => [time_id] => 17- [version_id] => 23048 [day] => 24 ) 
[33] => Array ( [id] => 2879 [person] => [time_id] => 17- [version_id] => 23048 [day] => 25 ) 
[34] => Array ( [id] => 2880 [person] => [time_id] => 17- [version_id] => 23048 [day] => 26 ) 
[35] => Array ( [id] => 2881 [person] => [time_id] => 17- [version_id] => 23048 [day] => 27 ) 
[36] => Array ( [id] => 3487 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23188 [day] => 2 ) 
[37] => Array ( [id] => 3488 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23188 [day] => 3 ) 
[38] => Array ( [id] => 3489 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23188 [day] => 4 ) 
[39] => Array ( [id] => 3490 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23188 [day] => 5 ) 
[40] => Array ( [id] => 3491 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23188 [day] => 6 ) 
[41] => Array ( [id] => 3642 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23212 [day] => 19 ) 
[42] => Array ( [id] => 3643 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23212 [day] => 21 ) 
[43] => Array ( [id] => 3694 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 10 ) 
[44] => Array ( [id] => 3695 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 11 ) 
[45] => Array ( [id] => 3696 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 12 ) 
[46] => Array ( [id] => 3697 [person] => [time_id] => 15-- [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 13 ) 
[47] => Array ( [id] => 3706 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 10 ) 
[48] => Array ( [id] => 3707 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 11 ) 
[49] => Array ( [id] => 3708 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 12 ) 
[50] => Array ( [id] => 3709 [person] => [time_id] => 9 [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 13 ) )
```

First array is array_unique of second array (version_id)

I need to create a new 2 dimensional array which will be the sum of these two arrays.
First dimension is a first array (version_is), second dimension is days (1-31).
If, for example days 2,4,5 don't have rest version_id's equal, they should get a lower version_id

for example

```
 Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 1 [time_id] => 9 [person] => )
            [1] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 2 [time_id] => 15 [person] => )
            [2] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 15 [time_id] => 15 [person] => )
            [3] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23225 [day] => 30 [time_id] => 9+ [person] => ))
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 1 [time_id] => 9 [person] => )
            [1] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 2 [time_id] => 17 [person] => )
            [2] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 15 [time_id] => 15 [person] => )
            [3] => Array  ( [version_id] => 23224 [day] => 30 [time_id] => 5+ [person] => )))
```

I hope you understand me :)

**GOT IT!**
Could you check is this is optimal solution?

```
foreach ($Array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $skey => $svalue) {
        $version_id=$Array[$key]['version_id'];
        for ($day=1; $day<=31; $day++) {
            if ($Array[$key]['day']==$day) {
                $New[$version_id][$day]['day']=$Array[$key]['day'];
                $New[$version_id][$day]['person']=$Array[$key]['person'];
                $New[$version_id][$day]['time_id']=$Array[$key]['time_id'];
                $New[$version_id][$day]['who']=$Array[$key]['who'];     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how ridiculous the next problem you might face, is going to be ;-)

Comment: If it is ridiculous then help me! ;P

Comment: I couldn't even understand the problem. too clumsy. you could clarify a bit

Comment: sorry, english is not my native language. I need to create new array using these two. First dimension tells me what's acctual version_id, second dimension contain days (1-31) and other variables for version_id. Look at example, dimension 0 have version_id 23225 and all datas for it, dimension 1 have 23224 and all datas for it. If days 1,2,3 and 5 havn't any data from version_id 23225 he could copy it from dimesnion 1 (23224). I hope now you understand me

Comment: Also remember to add the language name in the tags. It looks like PHP, but only after your edit...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a 2 Dimensional Array. In c++ you'd do something like this:

```
int varArray[9][59];
```